# how can i send metadata programmatically in android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, app-id

i'm using  facebookSDK to share text and images, but i need to send the app_id as parameter programmatically and not from the AndroidManifest.xml ... any suggestions ?

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
     android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = info.metaData;
String appId = bundle.getString("com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId");
```